# Highlight a listview's child

Tags: android, listview, focus

Could i highlight child of list view?
i tried many ways but it doesn't work.

```
list.getchildat(position).requestFocus;
```

and

list.setSelection(position);

and list.setselected("true").

Any propositions please?

Comment: Try to look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List17.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer:

```
@Override    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        // Make the newly clicked item the currently selected one.        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);    }
```

Go look at api demes: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List17.html

Comment: When i launch my application, i want the third item to be focused, without click without anything